# C# pagemethod autocomplete Materialize erro

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, materialize

Não consigo executar a minha função c# através do autocomplete do framework materialize. Não executa e não me retorna nenhum erro. Com bootstrap funciona.

Estou usando asp.net sem codebehind, tudo no mesmo arquivo.

Consigo chamar a função pelo console do chrome, mas não no autocompletar.

chamada javascript:

```
$('#autocomplete-input').autocomplete({
  data: function (request,response){
    PageMethods.GetAllSavedAddress("nextel", function (datax) {
      console.log("teste"); //ESSA LINHA TERIA QUE FUNCIONAR INDEPENDENTE DO RETORNO DO METODO
    return response(datax);
    })
  },
  limit: 20,
  onAutocomplete: function(val) {
    console.log(val);
  },
  minLength: 1,
});
```

coloquei um console.log logo depois da chamada do pagemethod, mas nem isso funciona.

Criei uma função JS pra chamar pelo console e funciona perfeitamente:

```
 function TesteX() {
            PageMethods.GetAllSavedAddress($('#autocomplete-input').val(), onSucess, onError);
            function onSucess(result) {
                   alert(result);
            }
            function onError(result) {
                console.log('Something wrong.');
            }
        }
```

Sei que o erro está nessa parte porque se eu popular na mão funciona. Exemplo:

```
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
    data: {
      "Apple": null,
      "Microsoft": null,
      "Google": null
    },
    limit: 20, 
    onAutocomplete: function(val) {
      // Callback function when value is autcompleted.
    },
    minLength: 1, 
  });
```

Ajudas super bem vindas, rs.

Comment: O que é `PageMethods.GetAllSavedAddress`?

Comment: Onde tem `C#` nos na sua pergunta?

Comment: PageMethods é um membro de System.Web.UI.

Comment: GetAllSavedAddress é um static Web Method C# que criei. Ele retorna um json. Em Jquery UI funciona, mas no materialize não

Comment: Isso que eu estava imaginando. Esse Javascript está em uma view Razor certo? Veja o resultado da renderização no browser e adicione na sua pergunta, PF.

Comment: Não. É um WebForm. E não me retorna nenhum erro, só não executa

Comment: Veja o resultado da renderização e posta aqui